# How to convert a String to blob in java?

Tags: java, blob

I have a String which contains a large mail body. I need to save it to the database in the form of blob. How to convert it to the `blob` in java? 
Sample String below:

```
<html><center> <body style='background-color: #e5e4e2;'> <table id='mainTable' style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'><tr> <td> <table style='width: 100%;background-color: #2B547E; height: 50px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'> <tr> <td width='50%'><img src="cid:image" height='50' width='150' style='padding-left: 10px;'></td> <td width='50%' style='text-align: right; color: white; font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px;'> </td></tr> </table> </td> </tr></table> <table id='mainTable1' style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'> <tr> <td> <table style='width: 100%; height: 50px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'><tr> <td width='50%' style='color:red;font-size:21px;'>Congratulations, Joselyn Valdes-Flores </td> <td width='50%' style='text-align: right; color: white; font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px;'> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style='font-size:18px;width:97%;font-style:italic'> This email confirms your Phone Interview  with Manager, Accounts Receivable  in   Burger King Corporation  You will be called at your mobile number </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <table  style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'><tr style='color:green'> Interview LineUp <th style='color:gray;font-size:21px;text-align:left;font-style: italic'>Interviewe</th><th  style='color:gray;font-size:21px;text-align:left;font-style: italic'>Timing1</th><th  style='color:gray;font-size:21px;text-align:left;font-style: italic'>Timing2</th></tr><tr><td>Jeet Chatterjee</td><td>12:00am</td><td>2:00am</td></tr><tr><td>Ramu</td><td>2:00am</td><td>4:00am</td></tr></table><table id='mainTable2' style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:12px;'><tr> <td style='font-size:18px; color:#2B547E;word-wrap: break-word;font-style: italic'> hii</td> </tr> </table> <table  style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'> <tr> <td style='font-size:18px;color:#2B547E;word-wrap: break-word;font-style: italic'> Best Regards,</td><td style='font-size:24px;color:#2B547E;word-wrap: break-word;font-style: italic'> Jeet Chatterjee</td></tr> </table></body> </center> </html>
```

I want to save it in a database in the blob column. How to do this??

Comment: Most databases save arbitrary "bytes" as BLOBs, so you can just give bytes of the string to the database driver.

Comment: For non-binary text, a CLOB would be more appropriate for text operations on the database level.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by getting `byte[]` content from `String`

```
byte[] byteData = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");//Better to specify encoding
Blob blobData = dbConnection.createBlob();
blobData.setBytes(1, byteData);
```

Moreover, you can directly store `String` to `BLOB` column.

Comment: why i need a dbConnection?

Comment: @lucifer To create `blob` instance you can use database connection Object.

Comment: without database connection i can not make blob object?

Comment: @lucifer No there is no use of Blob instance other than inserting blob data to blob column. Only way I know about is creating blob instance with db connection object.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks that would be more *elegant* though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by first getting the `byte[]` from `String` using:

`byte[] byteData = yourString.getBytes();`

and after that doing the next line of code:

`Blob docInBlob = new SerialBlob(byteData);`

Blob is from `java.sql` package and SerialBlob is from `javax.sql.rowset.serial package`.